# Methods & CRAN packages to predict probability using neural networks or others machine learning algorithms

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, neural-networks

I have a medical database containing 7 input variables (4 are binary) and a binary outcome variable (Survival: yes/no). My objective is to train and test an algorithm that predict probability of survival (not a binary output).

I used nnet package. But it returned for me a binary output (using "raw" and "class" type).
Which method can i use? 
Is there any R CRAN Packages to predict probability of survival using neural networks or others machine learning algorithms?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in the pros & cons of different ML algorithms for situations like this? Note that CV is not an R Q&A site (you may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)). Regarding your outcome variable, do you have survival durations or just yes / no? Might there be any censoring?

Comment: I have both. but my primer y outcome is 1-year-survival.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like to use the [caret package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) for predictive modeling, as it provided a unified interface to a variety of algorithms, including `nnet`.  It's very easy to get predicted probabilities for any model that supports them, neural networks included:

```
set.seed(42)
require(caret)
model <- train(Species~., data=iris, method='nnet', 
               trControl=trainControl(method='cv'))
model
probs <- predict(model, iris, type='prob')
head(probs)
     setosa versicolor    virginica
1 0.9881512 0.01143536 0.0004134043
2 0.9839565 0.01550938 0.0005341130
3 0.9866016 0.01293839 0.0004599962
4 0.9820605 0.01735453 0.0005849775
5 0.9884653 0.01113064 0.0004040207
6 0.9875201 0.01204961 0.0004302507
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this example. I had a problem with the `predict()` step because it showed `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Id1002025' not found`. I can't move on since I haven't found a solution to this and I want to simulate OP's goal for multi-time survival predictions.

Comment: @llorgge Very odd.  I am getting the same error when I re-run this code.  One of the newer versions of caret must have introduced a bug.  Oddly, if I try other `methods` (e.g. `rpart` or `glm` instead of `nnet`) I get the same error.  It must be a problem with the `predict` function in caret.

Comment: @llorgge I changed the example to use the iris dataset.  It would appear there is a very specific bug in caret when using the formula interface for classification models that contain factors.

Comment: just wondering if this method can predict survival risk in different time points ie 1, 2, 3 years? I tried applying it into a `SimSurv()` dataset but like declare a `times` list with the time points into the `train()` function but an error occurs `length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`.

Comment: @llorgge You should probably post a separate question, with a reproducible example.  I'm not sure caret works with survival data.

Comment: [here is my question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81141/coxpn-and-cphs-predictsurvprobs-equivalent-in-nnet-or-neuralnet). Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Ok, but your predict function doesn't take test set in order to do prediction.

Comment: @HaskellFun It does take a test set.  see `?predict.train`.  I updated my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3):

I would second the recommendation of an "ensemble" method such as Random Forests. There is a variant of RF, "randomSurvivalForest" that is specific to survival analysis. Here is a link to the the R manual for the package [randomSurvivalForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomSurvivalForest/randomSurvivalForest.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at package [RSNNS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/index.html), which provides an R interface to the package [SNNS](http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/SNNS/), with ample functionality for general neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try for example the glm function with the family=binomial and the logit link (or the probit) doing a logistic regression, which outputs are probabilitys.. Here you have a link
[logistic regression R](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/courses/ling289/logistic.pdf)

You also can try with trees or with "ensembles" of trees , boosting, bagging or random forest wuth packages like rpart ,randomForest etc If your dependent variable is 1/0 you will have outcomes with estimated proportions.

[CART trees R](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html)

[randomForest CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf)
.