# Neural networks output probability estimates?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks

Suppose my training data contains ~100 variables, and each example is tagged as "success" or "failure".

I understand how a neural network can be used to try and predict success vs failure based on the variables.

However I am interested in the neural network outputting the *posterior probability* rather than success or failure. In fact, I evaluate the efficacy of the NN based on how accurate the probabilities are (eg. AUROC over the entire dataset) rather than % of cases with correct prediction.

Are NN's the right tool for the job here and if so how do you structure the NN to output this?

(NOTE: I'm a ML newbie!)

Comment: Some answers were given to this question in an [earlier post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44223/methods-cran-packages-to-predict-probability-using-neural-networks-or-others-m)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your activation function is for example logistic, then it will output continuous value between 0-1, or you can use softmax in the case of multiple outcome variables.

Answer (score 8):

Just for people who are still interested in this question:

Softmax of state-of-art deep learning models is more of a score than probability estimates.

Most deep networks nowadays are overconfident, check the follow paper if you are interested:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04599.pdf

Answer (score 3):

In your NN, if you use a softmax output layer, you'll actually end up with an output vector of probabilities.  This is actually the most common output layer to use for multi-class classification problems.  To fetch the class label, you can perform an argmax() on the output vector to retrieve the index of the max probability across all labels.